# how to get the relative path of a jar file from outside in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a project structure like the one below:

```
└── core
    ├── lib
    │   └── some.jar
    └── src
        └── main
            └── main.py
```

Now I am trying to access the `some.jar` inside the main.py file. It works fine with the absolute path but when I try to do something like below, it fails.

```
file:///../../lib/some.jar
```

I also tried the below code:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "lib")
```

but It gives the path as below:

```
/Users/IdeaProjects/getmesomeproject/core/src/main/lib
```

Is there anyway to pass the relative path of the `JAR` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pathlib` to get the parent path

```
from pathlib import Path

os.path.join(Path(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))).parent.parent, "lib")
```

This should give you

```
/Users/IdeaProjects/RankedMatchmaking/core/lib
```

Comment: Yes, but is there any way that it should recognize may be from the project path? because I would be uploading the jar in the package so in the remote location there would be no`/Users/IdeaProjects` or will it work?

Comment: @RushHour This should work any where, the path is based on the machine you are running on.

Comment: What if I hit via API gateway? will this work there too?

Comment: @RushHour I'm not sure what you mean, but as I said the path is built based on the machine you are running on, it only depends on the project structure, not on where the project is located.

Comment: cool. Thanks @Guy.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use file path like  **../../lib/some.jar** in main.py file.

Comment: I already mentioned that doesn't work.